# Why does Wolfram Alpha give different answers to this algebraic equation depending on how it is entered?

Tags: solution-verification, wolfram-alpha, calculator

I am trying to solve the equation $Ce^{-\sqrt L t} + De^{\sqrt L t} = Ce^{-\sqrt L (t + 2m\pi)} + De^{\sqrt L (t + 2m\pi)}$ for $L$.

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C%20*%20e%5E%28-sqrt%28L%29%20*%20t%29%20%2B%20D%20*%20e%5E%28sqrt%28L%29%20*%20t%29%20%3D%20C%20*%20e%5E%28-sqrt%28L%29%20*%20%28t%20%2B%202%20*%20m%20*%20pi%29%29%20%2B%20D%20*%20e%5E%28sqrt%28L%29%20*%20%28t%20%2B%202%20*%20m%20*%20pi%29%29) Wolfram Alpha returns the solution $m = \frac{in}{\sqrt L}$, which is easily seen to be $L = -\frac{n^2}{m^2}$, but when I add the instruction to solve for $L$, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C%20*%20e%5E%28-sqrt%28L%29%20*%20t%29%20%2B%20D%20*%20e%5E%28sqrt%28L%29%20*%20t%29%20%3D%20C%20*%20e%5E%28-sqrt%28L%29%20*%20%28t%20%2B%202%20*%20m%20*%20pi%29%29%20%2B%20D%20*%20e%5E%28sqrt%28L%29%20*%20%28t%20%2B%202%20*%20m%20*%20pi%29%29%2C%20solve%20for%20L) we see WA drop the $n^2$ and return $L = -\frac{1}{m^2}$.  Similarly in the more complicated solution, $n$ is missing on the second WA page.

Why is WA doing this?  Is there any way to avoid the misinformation it is returning?

Comment: In the first case, WA decides to solve for $t$. In the second, it's solving for $L$, and this is more complicated because it needs to deal with the branch cuts associated with either the square roots in the expression or the logarithms that show up in the solution.  I suspect that WA doesn't dive this deeply into things.  I you solve it in Mathematica, however, it yields the more general solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha depends on the Wolfram Language in Mathematica and it takes some getting used to the non intuitive way that Mathematica works.

Your example query

> $\texttt{C*e^(-sqrt(L)*t)+D*e^(sqrt(L)*t)=}$
> $\texttt{C*e^(-sqrt(L)*(t+2*m*pi))+D*e^(sqrt(L)*(t+2*m*pi))}$

to WA was interpreted as the Wolfram Language command

```
Reduce[C/E^(Sqrt[L]*t) + D*E^(Sqrt[L]*t) ==
 C/E^(Sqrt[L]*(2*m*Pi + t)) + D*E^(Sqrt[L]*(2*m*Pi + t)),
 {C, D, L, m, t}]
```

This returns essentially five different
solutions. The first three are
$$ L=0 \tag{1}$$
$$ C=0,\quad D=0 \tag{2}$$
$$ C\ne0,\quad D\ne0,\quad D=C,\quad L=0 \tag{3}$$
The next two depend on an integer $\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\,$ as follows
$$ \sqrt{L}\ne0,\quad m=\frac{in}{\sqrt{L}} \tag{4}$$
$$ D\!\ne\!0, C\!\ne\!0, \sqrt{L}\!\ne\!0,
t\!=\!-m\pi \!+\! \frac{i\pi n}{\sqrt{L}}
\!+\!\frac{\log(\frac CD)}{2\sqrt{L}} \tag{5}$$
Note that for equation $(3)$ the $\,D\ne0\,$ is
replaced with $\,C\ne0\,$ in the WA display.

So far so good. Now you appended
"$\,\texttt{, solve for L}\,$" to your query
and WA interpreted this more literally as

```
Solve[C/E^(Sqrt[L]*t) + D*E^(Sqrt[L]*t) ==
 C/E^(Sqrt[L]*(2*m*Pi + t)) + D*E^(Sqrt[L]*(2*m*Pi + t)),
 {L}]
```

Note the replacement of `Solve` for `Reduce` and
the list of variables is only `{L}`.
The two solutions returned which depend on an
integer $\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\,$ are
$$ L = -\frac{n^2}{m^2} \tag{6} $$
$$ L = \frac{(2i\pi n+\log(\frac CD))^2}{4(m\pi+t)^2} \tag{7} $$
As you noted, the $\,n^2\,$ is dropped from the
equation $(6)$ for some reason. Similarly, the
$\,2i\pi n\,$ is dropped in equation $(7)$ for
some reason. Probably a bug in the WA result
display. The underlying Wolfram Language code
returns the correct results, but WA mangles them.

You asked

> Why is WA doing this?

It is very hard to answer this because the WA
system is proprietary and Wolfram does not give
enough information about how to control what WA
does interfacing to Mathematica. As I explained,
in the first query, WA decided to use `Reduce`
and in the second query, `Solve` was used. Hard
to explain why it does this.

> Is there any way to avoid the misinformation it is returning?

Of course, the best way is to use Mathematica's
Wolfram Language directly which is possible using
the [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/).